# when I am using bash install bootstrap I get bash : bower : command not found

Tags: bash

I am using bower to install bootstrap to my code
but it is not getting installed 
by the error line

```
bash : bower : command not found
```

I am using this command to install bootstrap

```
bower install bootstrap
```

after seeing some old questions I used

```
npm install -g grunt-bower-cli
```

but still the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install bower globaly with:

```
npm install -g bower
```

And then you can do:

```
bower install bootstrap
```

Comment: thanx 
thanx alot
sorry to ask the same question again
but I was stuck and unable to find the answer in previously asked questions
thanx mate

Comment: No problem, may the force be with you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install bower globally in your system first, go to command prompt run the following command

```
npm install -g bower
```

than check the version of  bower

```
 bower -v
```

and than run following command to install bootstrap

```
bower install bootstrap
```